# javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider - 10

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have found many similar questions on stackoverflow but the answers are not helping me. I am using JSR-303 Bean validation in my Rest api project to provide validation to the existing bean class. I have added all the dependencies but I am getting this error.

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)[272:wrap_mvn_javax.validation_validation-api_1.0.0.GA:0]
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)[272:wrap_mvn_javax.validation_validation-api_1.0.0.GA:0]
    at com.uk.aviva.integration.LookupUkAddress.ValidateAddress.validateRequest(ValidateAddress.java:27)[277:ukAddress:0.0.8.SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_11]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.HandleFaultInterceptor.process(HandleFaultInterceptor.java:41)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[144:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.12.0.redhat-611412]
```

I saw a lot of people facing the same issue, however the solution given was to add hibernate-validator version 4.0 or above to the classpath. But I am already using hibernate-validator version 5.0.1.FINAL. Here are my pom entries

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there something that I've missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way to avoid the error and it works. To avoid it use the hibernate-validator dependency version 4.2.1.FINAL with javax.validation version 1.1.0.FINAL. And add these two to your classpath. That solved the error for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You are mixing Bean Validation 1.1 API jars with Hibernate Validator 4.x jars which is based on Bean Validation 1.0. You either need to use Bean Validation 1.0 together with Validator 4.x or you upgrade to Validator 5.x and use the Bean Validation 1.1 API. If you are some dependency management tool (maven, ivy,...), you should be able to just specify the Validator version you want to use and the right Bean Validation version gets added transitively.

Comment: So, just adding Hibernate Validator version 5.x would solve this issue ?

Comment: Using the right combination of jars would do it. Validator 4.x with Bean Validation 1.0 and Validator 5.x with Bean Validation 1.1.

Comment: Yes I tried using Validator 5.x with Bean Validation 1.1. And I was getting missing requirement [318.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.classmate)(version>=0.8.0)), this error.